# UICollectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind called three times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I've a `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionView` attached on it. The problem is that `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` is called three times and not just one like in `UITableView`.

Ideas ?

Comment: What you are expecting to happen?

Comment: Called once... as in `UITableView`

Answer (score 1):

For `UICollectionView` supplementary view's are nothing but `Section Header` and `Section Footer`. `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` called two times for each section if you have already registered ***Classes*** for `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` and `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter`. So the calling of ***viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind*** is depending on the number of the sections and availability of Section header/footer

Comment: I've registered only for `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader`

Comment: and you have only one section?

Comment: Yes, only one section

Comment: i have same problem.. have you found the solutions?

Comment: Same thing here — really mysterious!

Answer (score 1):

i do not know exactly why this happened, but i have a weird solution.  before you return the UICollectionReusableView in the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind methord,check the num of datasource,just like this

```
if kind == CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader
    {

        if let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: String(ImageDetailHeaderView), forIndexPath: indexPath) as? ImageDetailHeaderView
        {
            let bannerViewModel=ImageDetailHeaderVM(requestUrlStr: viewModel.headerRequestUrlStr, requestParams: viewModel.headerRequestParams)
            if vm.cellModelList.count>0
            {
                ***// only the datasource is not empty ,config the SupplementaryView***
                header.vm=bannerViewModel
                header.tagClickedHandler=tagClickedHandler
                header.shareButtonClicked=shareButtonClicked
                header.delegate=self
            }
            return header

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually going to happen N times depending on whether you're reloading the collection view or scrolling the sections out of view and bringing them back.  The viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind is going to get called whenever a section that has a header or footer gets displayed in the view